# node.js express.js object is not a function call_non_function

Tags: node.js, express

I have this error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION (native)
```

For this line:

```
var app=express();
```

I tryed to install express/connect again, but.. nothing.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm express 2.5.8.

my code:

*error:*

```
    var http=require('http');
    var app=express();
    var server=http.createServer(app);
```

(i forget why i need to use this code, i think for cookie handshake works.
I have resole the probleme (hanskake cookie) editing manager.js, so i dont need to use this code. But can be interesting to understand why no works (and why i wanted to use)).

*no error:*
`var app=express.createServer();`

Comment: We need more of your code, show us how you require the Express lib.

Comment: Also, please submit the Express version. The API changed quite a bit between 2.* and 3.0.0alpha.

Comment: it seems that you are using version 2.x, in 2.x use 'var app = express.createServer();'  To see the version, run in console 'express -v' or see 'package.json' of express module

Comment: i'm very sorry, i use this code because i need this to resolve a problem with handshake cookie, but i forget what. So i'm 2.5.8. I require express like that: expres=require('express');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the wrong express version. You can only create the server with `express()` in v3.x.x. Before this version, express can not be called as a Function. Try either changing your code to create the app the old way or try updating express.